# Estimated size izpack

Tags: windows-10, java, installer

I would like to display the size of my application(I use to create the installer izpack)  in Control Panel > Programs and Features:

The solution I found is to set the estimated size statically in registerSpec.xml

```
          <value name="EstimatedSize" 
           keypath="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$UNINSTALL_NAME"
           root="HKLM" dword="6125"/>
```

But I'd like to calculate the size dynamically ..didn't find a way to go

Thank you !